# Are there quasi "official" rankings of board games?

Tags: recommendations

I'm interested whether there are surveys of the best board games put out by board game manufacturers or evaluators such as gaming magazines or boardgamegeek that are considered authoritative. Or is there an official popularity competition between board games or a world cup of board games?

Comment: I assume when you say "official" you don't actually mean you're looking for there to be some sort of official governing body charged with deciding what the best games are? Do popularity contests (i.e. people voting on their favorite) satisfy what you're looking for, whether they're just reviews from everyday people or awards given by critics?

Comment: [List of Game of the Year awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_the_Year_awards_(board_games))

Comment: Hi @freekvd why won't post this as an answer?

Comment: @BrunoEstrazulas I would if this question had not been put on hold. I will if it gets reopened.

Comment: DrJim - Prizes for best board games (which I suspect would work for your "competition between board games") tend to only be for *new* board games. @freekvd's lists link is for these. Zack's answer gives more of an "all-time" ranking.

Comment: I did my best to clarify the question by asking for "authoritative" surveys and nominate it for reopening in its current form.

Comment: I still think it is a bad question.  "Authoritative" is too nebulous, and the question boils down to a recommendation question (of recommendations no less).

Answer (score 4):

[BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com) is a very comprehensive list of board games, [their relative rankings](https://boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgame), and reviews, commentary, and more for all things board games. They also have a convention, the BGG.CON.

Comment: Hi Zack. I've proposed an additional link in your answer, direct to BGG's ranking page, as I think this helps answer the question better. Please feel free to accept/reject as you feel fit.